# Do $X$ and $Y$ have the same cardinality if their families of finite subsets do?

Tags: reference-request, set-theory, lo.logic

Let $X$ and $Y$ be sets. It is undecidable in ZFC whether $2^{|X|} = 2^{|Y|}$ implies $|X| = |Y|$ (in Cohen's original model for ZFC + $\neg$CH, one has $2^{\aleph_0} = 2^{\aleph_1}$). What if we restrict our attention to the *finite* parts of $X$ and $Y$?

**Question.** Do $X$ and $Y$ have the same cardinality if the families of *finite* subsets of both sets do?

As noted by Nik Weaver [in a comment](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/450025/do-x-and-y-have-the-same-cardinality-if-their-families-of-finite-subsets-do#comment1162981_450025), the answer is yes when we assume in the background to be working with the axioms of ZFC. But, what about ZF?

I feel this must be either basic or very well known (to those who know it very well).

Comment: You state yourself that the question of whether $X$ and $Y$ have the same cardinality is undecidable in ZFC, then you make it part of your question. The lesser part of your question seems to be: If $X$ and $Y$ have the same cardinality, then does the set of all finite subsets of $X$ have the same cardinality as the set of all finite subsets of $Y.$ That one has an easy affirmative answer: If $X$ and $Y$ have the same cardinality, then there is a function $f:X\to Y$ that is injective and surjective. For finite sets $Z\subseteq X,$ show that$\,\ldots\qquad$

Comment: $\ldots\,$the mapping $Z\mapsto\{ f(x):x\in X\} \subseteq Y$ is a bijection between the set of all finite subsets of $X$ have the same cardinality as the set of all finite subsets of $Y.$ Conclude that those both have the same cardinality. $\qquad$

Comment: I think this is just the fact that (in ZFC) any infinite set has the same cardinality as the set of all of its finite subsets. So yes, if the sets of finite subsets of $X$ and $Y$ have the same cardinality then so do $X$ and $Y$.

Comment: @NikWeaver Thanks! And a ref for the statement that "An infinite set has, in ZFC, the same cardinality as the collection of its finite parts" is essentially Corollary 8.13 in Chapter 0 of Hungerford's _Algebra_.

Comment: @MichaelHardy I'm not asking whether $|X| = |Y|$ implies that the family $\mathcal P_{\rm fin}(X)$ of finite subsets of $X$ has the same cardinality as the family $\mathcal P_{\rm fin}(Y)$ of finite subsets of $Y$. I'm rather asking whether $|\mathcal P_{\rm fin}(X)| = |\mathcal P_{\rm fin}(Y)|$ implies that $|X| = |Y|$.

Comment: The answer is yes under choice.

Comment: But I don't know right away what the situation is without choice.

Comment: This seems like an interesting question (without choice as per the comment above).  I don't understand why people are voting to close it.  @SalvoTringali you should modify your *question* to reflect the fact that it is about ZF, not ZFC.

Comment: Not a solution, but I think that if $A$ is Dedekind-infinite and $|A^2|\geq^*|\mathscr{P}(A)|$ then we have that $A^2$, $[A]^{{<}\omega}$, $[A^2]^{{<}\omega}$, and $\mathscr{P}(A)$ all surject onto each other, while only some inject into each other.

Comment: @MikhailKatz The original question did not indicate that this was intended to be thought in ZF, and in ZFC it is indeed a trivial well-known fact (as even the OP suspected), whence my vote to migrate to Maths Sack Exchange. Now the question has changed

Answer (score 16, accepted):

It can be proved in $\mathsf{ZF}$ that ``for all cardianls $\mathfrak{a},\mathfrak{b}$, if $\mathrm{fin}(\mathfrak{a})=\mathrm{fin}(\mathfrak{b})$, then $\mathfrak{a}=\mathfrak{b}$'' implies $\mathsf{AC}$. Here $\mathrm{fin}(\mathfrak{a})$ denotes the cardinality of the set of all finite subsets of a set which is of cardinality $\mathfrak{a}$.

Assume that, for all cardianls $\mathfrak{a},\mathfrak{b}$, if $\mathrm{fin}(\mathfrak{a})=\mathrm{fin}(\mathfrak{b})$, then $\mathfrak{a}=\mathfrak{b}$. We prove $\mathsf{AC}$ by showing that, for an arbitrary limit ordinal $\lambda$, $\mathrm{V}_\lambda$ is well-orderable. Let $\mathfrak{a}$ be the cardinality of $\mathrm{V}_\lambda$ and let $\kappa$ be the Hartogs number of $\mathrm{V}_\lambda$, i.e., the first ordinal that cannot be mapped injectively into $\mathrm{V}_\lambda$. Note that every finite subset of $\mathrm{V}_\lambda$ is an element of $\mathrm{V}_\lambda$, so $\mathrm{fin}(\mathfrak{a})=\mathfrak{a}$.

It suffices to prove that $\mathrm{fin}(\mathfrak{a}+\kappa)=\mathrm{fin}(\mathfrak{a}\cdot\kappa)$, since then by our assumption we would have $\mathfrak{a}+\kappa=\mathfrak{a}\cdot\kappa$, and thus $\mathfrak{a}$ is well-ordered by a lemma of Tarski. Clearly, $\mathrm{fin}(\mathfrak{a}+\kappa)=\mathrm{fin}(\mathfrak{a})\cdot\mathrm{fin}(\kappa)=\mathfrak{a}\cdot\kappa$. It remains to show that $\mathrm{fin}(\mathfrak{a}\cdot\kappa)=\mathfrak{a}\cdot\kappa$. It is proved as follows.

Let $u$ be an arbitrary finite subset of $\mathrm{V}_\lambda\times\kappa$.
Then $\mathrm{ran}(u)=\{\alpha\mid\exists x(\langle x,\alpha\rangle\in u)\}$ is a finite subset of $\kappa$, and thus there is a unique isomorphism $h_u$ of $\mathrm{ran}(u)$ onto some natural number. Note that $u$ is uniquely determined by $\langle\mathrm{ran}(u),\{\langle x,h_u(\alpha)\rangle\mid\langle x,\alpha\rangle\in u\}\rangle$, so
$$
\mathrm{fin}(\mathfrak{a}\cdot\kappa)\leqslant\mathrm{fin}(\kappa)\cdot\mathfrak{a}=\mathfrak{a}\cdot\kappa,
$$
which completes the proof.$\quad\square$

Comment: ${\sf fin}(\mathfrak{a})=\mathfrak{a}$? What? Do you mean $|{\sf fin}(\mathfrak{a})|=\mathfrak{a}$, or ${\sf fin}(\mathfrak{a})^{V_\lambda}={\sf fin}(\mathfrak{a})$, or something like this? (and obviously you want $\lambda$ to be a nonzero limit ordinal)

Comment: @ Alec $\mathrm{fin}(\mathfrak{a})$ is a cardinal (the cardinality of the set of all finite subsets of a set which is of cardinality $\mathfrak{a}$).

Comment: Ah, my bad, I somehow missed the first paragraph last night -- very nice!

Answer (score 11):

If $\mathrm{ZF}$ is consistent, then it does not prove the statement.

Let $\left<x_n\right>_{n<\omega}$ be generic
for the finite support product of an $\omega$-sequence of Cohen forcings. Let $C=\{x_n\}_{n<\omega}$
and let $M=L(C\cup\{C\})$.
So $M\models \mathrm{ZF}$.
Let $\Theta$ be the least ordinal which is not the surjective image of $C$ in $M$.
Then the claim is that $M\models \text{$``|\mathcal{P}_{<\omega}(X)|=|\mathcal{P}_{<\omega}(Y)|$ but $|X|\neq|Y|$"}$ where $X=C\cup\Theta$ and $Y=\mathbb{R}^M\cup\Theta$, giving
counterexamples to the question in $M$.

A standard observation: given $x\in\mathbb{R}^M$, note that there is
a finite set $S\subseteq C$
such that $x$ is $\mathrm{OD}_{S\cup\{C\}}^{M}$,
and hence by homogeneity, in fact $x\in L[S]$.
Let the *support* $S_x$ of $x$ be the least such set. (Note that if $S$, $S'$ are two such sets,
then $x$ is also $\mathrm{OD}_{(S\cap S')\cup\{C\}}^{M}$, by mutual genericity: letting $T=S\cap S'$,
then $x\in L[S]\cap L[S']=L[T][S\setminus T]\cap L[T][S'\setminus T]$,  so $x\in L[T]$.)

Given a finite set $A\subseteq \mathbb{R}^M$,
let the *support* $S_A$ of $A$ be $S_A=S_{x_0}\cup S_{x_1}\cup\dotsb\cup S_{x_{n-1}}$ where $A=\{x_0,\dotsc,x_{n-1}\}$. Note that the map $A\mapsto S_A$
is in $L(C\cup\{C\})$.

Note also that since $S_A$ is a finite set of reals, it is canonically wellordered, just by using the restriction of the standard linear order of the reals. Let $<_A$ be this wellorder.

Now to see that $M\models\text{$``|\mathcal{P}_{<\omega}(C\cup\Theta)|=|\mathcal{P}_{<\omega}(\mathbb{R}^M\cup\Theta)|$"}$, we just need to see that $M$ has an injection
$$ \pi:\mathcal{P}_{<\omega}(\mathbb{R}^M\cup\Theta)\to\mathcal{P}_{<\omega}(C\cup\Theta),$$
since in fact $C\cup\Theta\subseteq \mathbb{R}^M\cup\Theta$.
Let $B\subseteq\mathbb{R}^M\cup\Theta$
be finite; we will define $\pi(B)$.
Let $A=B\cap\mathbb{R}^M$ and set $\pi(B)\cap C=S_A$.
Let $A'=B\cap\Theta$ and set $\pi(B)\cap\Theta=\{\gamma\}$
where $\gamma$ is the G"odel code of the pair $(\alpha,\beta)$, where $\alpha$ naturally codes $A'$
and $\beta$ is the position of $A$ in the $L[S_A]$-wellorder, where we use $<_A$ to order $S_A$ in a specific manner, so that $\beta$ is then uniquely determined. So overall, we define
$$ \pi(B)= S_A\cup\{\gamma\}.$$
Note that $\pi$ is an injection.

It remains to see that $M\models \text{$``|C\cup\Theta|\neq|\mathbb{R}^M\cup\Theta|$"}$, for which it suffices
to see that $M\models``\text{There is no injection $\sigma:\mathbb{R}^M\to C\cup\Theta$"}$.
So suppose we have such an injective $\sigma\in M$.
Then there is a finite set $A\subseteq C$
such that $\sigma\in\mathrm{OD}^{M}_{A\cup\{C\}}$.
But then if $x\in\mathbb{R}^M$
and $\sigma(x)\in\Theta$,
then by homogeneity, $x\in L[A]$.
In particular, if $x\in C$
and $\sigma(x)\in\Theta$, then $x\in A$,
so there are only finitely many such $x$.
So if $x\in C\setminus A$ then $\sigma(x)\in C$,
but $\sigma(x)\notin A$, since $x\notin L[A]$.
So in fact if $x\in C\setminus A$
then $\sigma(x)=x$.
But now letting $x_0,x_1\in C\setminus A$
with $x_0\neq x_1$,
we have  $x_0\oplus x_1\notin L[A]$,
so $\sigma(x_0\oplus x_1)\notin A\cup\Theta$,
but also $\sigma(x_0\oplus x_1)\notin C\setminus A$,
since $\sigma``(C\setminus A)=C\setminus A$.
This is a contradiction.

Comment: TeX note: `\backslash` is semantically a quotient, not a difference; compare $C\backslash A$ vs. $C \setminus A$ `$C\backslash A$ vs. $C \setminus A$`.  I have edited to use the latter.  What is the meaning of $\sigma``(C \setminus A)$?

Comment: @LSpice $f``X$ means $\{f(x)\mid x\in X\}$ usually.

Comment: What's then the difference between $f``X$ and $f(X)$? It seems that $\sigma$ is a function and $C \setminus A$ is a subset of its domain of definition. (Sorry if the question is off, but I am not familiar with much of the notation used in this post and would like to understand more.)

Comment: @SalvoTringali In set theory, it happens all too often that a *subset* of the domain of some function is at the same time an *element* of the domain of the function. Thus it is vital to use notation that distinguishes between the value of a function $f$ applied to an argument ($f(x)$) and the image of a subset of the domain under $f$ (here denoted $f``X$, but $f[X]$ is also common). In many other fields, both are denoted the same as $f(X)$.

Comment: @CalliopeRyan-Smith, [re](https://mathoverflow.net/posts/comments/1163228), thanks for explaining!  On another `\`\`` note, the [edit](https://mathoverflow.net/revisions/450084/3) replacing $M \models \text{"…"}$ `M \models \text{"…"}` by `M \models \`\`\text{…"}` (I can't find escapes that lets the TeX compile properly here) was not really appropriate—notice the ugly mismatched quotes!  You *could* do `M \models \`\`\text{…}''`, but that still doesn't really typeset properly.  If the straight quotes bother you, $M \models \text{“…”}$ `M \models \text{“…”}` (Unicode quotes) is best.

Comment: No offense, Farmer, but it is very clear this was written by an inner model theorist. You're describing the Cohen model; your $\Theta$ is just $\omega_1$, so your $Y$ is just $\Bbb R$, and in a nutshell, you're just making the argument that in the Cohen model every real has a unique finite set of Cohen and an ordinal to define it. (No complaints about the observation, of course. Well done.)